# automatically download without URL

Tags: download

I have a question about the following. I want to automatically download a file which is not available through an URL, but through "javascript: postback()". It's about the following file: http://elia.be/repository/pages/877f075274f440d8a049107cfec0bddf.aspx and then the ".csv" button at the right hand side of the site (right side of 'Gegevens van de getoonde grafiek inladen'). How can I automatically download this data e.g. each hour and save the csv file on my computer?

It would be great if someone could help me. Thank you very much!!

Comment: What language? We need **much** more details.

Answer (score 0):

You send a `POST` request to the following URL:

```
http://elia.be/repository/pages/877f075274f440d8a049107cfec0bddf.aspx
```

With the parameters outlined in the `<form>` element's children.

The magic parameter is `ACTIONTARGET`, and its value is `DownloadCsv.GraphData`.

Comment: Thank you! So I'm not advanced in this, but I will try to. But is it possible to run this in a windows scheduler (using cmd??)?

Comment: Nope. Windows doesn't include anything like that. You could try finding a `curl` binary.